# Full page loader in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to make a full page loader for my NextJS app like in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/yaz9x42g/8/. So once the content is loaded, it should be revealed in this cool way. I'd like to make a reausable component which I could use in different cases. I tried the following:

```
'use client';

import { useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

export function Loader() {
   useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const fpl = document.getElementById('full-page-loader');
    const onLoad = () => {
      fpl!.classList.add('hide');
    };

    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
      onLoad();
    } else {
      window.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
      return () => window.removeEventListener('load', onLoad);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id='full-page-loader'>
      <svg
        height='76'
        viewBox='0 0 12 10'
        fill='none'
        xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
      >
        <path
          d='M1.33346 8.50746C1.14794 8.50746 0.974009 8.47302 0.811674 8.40413C0.649339 8.33525 0.50633 8.23957 0.382646 8.11711C0.266693 7.99464 0.17393 7.85687 0.104358 7.70379C0.034786 7.54305 0 7.37084 0 7.18714V0H0.881246V7.18714C0.881246 7.31726 0.923762 7.42442 1.00879 7.50861C1.09383 7.5928 1.20205 7.6349 1.33346 7.6349H1.43782C1.56924 7.6349 1.67746 7.5928 1.76249 7.50861C1.84752 7.42442 1.89004 7.31726 1.89004 7.18714V2.81286C1.89004 2.69039 1.84752 2.58706 1.76249 2.50287C1.67746 2.41102 1.56924 2.3651 1.43782 2.3651H1.11315V1.49254H1.43782C1.62335 1.49254 1.79341 1.52698 1.94802 1.59587C2.11035 1.66475 2.25336 1.76043 2.37704 1.88289C2.50073 2.00536 2.59736 2.14696 2.66693 2.30769C2.7365 2.46077 2.77129 2.62916 2.77129 2.81286V7.18714C2.77129 7.37084 2.7365 7.54305 2.66693 7.70379C2.59736 7.85687 2.50073 7.99464 2.37704 8.11711C2.25336 8.23957 2.11035 8.33525 1.94802 8.40413C1.79341 8.47302 1.62335 8.50746 1.43782 8.50746H1.33346Z'
          fill='white'
        />
        <path
          d='M3.93834 4.55798H4.94713V2.81286C4.94713 2.69039 4.90462 2.58706 4.81959 2.50287C4.73455 2.41102 4.62633 2.3651 4.49492 2.3651H4.39056C4.25914 2.3651 4.15092 2.41102 4.06589 2.50287C3.98086 2.58706 3.93834 2.69039 3.93834 2.81286V4.55798ZM4.39056 8.50746C4.20503 8.50746 4.0311 8.47302 3.86877 8.40413C3.70643 8.33525 3.56342 8.23957 3.43974 8.11711C3.32379 7.99464 3.23102 7.85687 3.16145 7.70379C3.09188 7.54305 3.05709 7.37084 3.05709 7.18714V2.81286C3.05709 2.62916 3.09188 2.46077 3.16145 2.30769C3.23102 2.14696 3.32379 2.00536 3.43974 1.88289C3.56342 1.76043 3.70643 1.66475 3.86877 1.59587C4.0311 1.52698 4.20503 1.49254 4.39056 1.49254H4.49492C4.68044 1.49254 4.85437 1.52698 5.01671 1.59587C5.17904 1.66475 5.31818 1.76043 5.43414 1.88289C5.55782 2.00536 5.65445 2.14696 5.72402 2.30769C5.80132 2.46077 5.83998 2.62916 5.83998 2.81286V5.44202H3.93834V7.18714C3.93834 7.31726 3.98086 7.42442 4.06589 7.50861C4.15092 7.5928 4.25914 7.6349 4.39056 7.6349H4.49492C4.62633 7.6349 4.73455 7.5928 4.81959 7.50861C4.90462 7.42442 4.94713 7.31726 4.94713 7.18714V6.75086H5.83998V7.18714C5.83998 7.37084 5.80132 7.54305 5.72402 7.70379C5.65445 7.85687 5.55782 7.99464 5.43414 8.11711C5.31818 8.23957 5.17904 8.33525 5.01671 8.40413C4.85437 8.47302 4.68044 8.50746 4.49492 8.50746H4.39056Z'
          fill='white'
        />
        <path
          d='M7.01835 4.55798H8.02715V2.81286C8.02715 2.69039 7.98463 2.58706 7.8996 2.50287C7.81457 2.41102 7.70634 2.3651 7.57493 2.3651H7.47057C7.33916 2.3651 7.23093 2.41102 7.1459 2.50287C7.06087 2.58706 7.01835 2.69039 7.01835 2.81286V4.55798ZM7.47057 8.50746C7.28504 8.50746 7.11111 8.47302 6.94878 8.40413C6.78644 8.33525 6.64344 8.23957 6.51975 8.11711C6.4038 7.99464 6.31104 7.85687 6.24146 7.70379C6.17189 7.54305 6.13711 7.37084 6.13711 7.18714V2.81286C6.13711 2.62916 6.17189 2.46077 6.24146 2.30769C6.31104 2.14696 6.4038 2.00536 6.51975 1.88289C6.64344 1.76043 6.78644 1.66475 6.94878 1.59587C7.11111 1.52698 7.28504 1.49254 7.47057 1.49254H7.57493C7.76045 1.49254 7.93438 1.52698 8.09672 1.59587C8.25905 1.66475 8.3982 1.76043 8.51415 1.88289C8.63783 2.00536 8.73446 2.14696 8.80403 2.30769C8.88134 2.46077 8.91999 2.62916 8.91999 2.81286V5.44202H7.01835V7.18714C7.01835 7.31726 7.06087 7.42442 7.1459 7.50861C7.23093 7.5928 7.33916 7.6349 7.47057 7.6349H7.57493C7.70634 7.6349 7.81457 7.5928 7.8996 7.50861C7.98463 7.42442 8.02715 7.31726 8.02715 7.18714V6.75086H8.91999V7.18714C8.91999 7.37084 8.88134 7.54305 8.80403 7.70379C8.73446 7.85687 8.63783 7.99464 8.51415 8.11711C8.3982 8.23957 8.25905 8.33525 8.09672 8.40413C7.93438 8.47302 7.76045 8.50746 7.57493 8.50746H7.47057Z'
          fill='white'
        />
        <path
          d='M10.11 10V9.12744H10.6549C10.7864 9.12744 10.8946 9.08534 10.9796 9.00115C11.0724 8.92461 11.1188 8.82128 11.1188 8.69116V2.81286C11.1188 2.69039 11.0724 2.58706 10.9796 2.50287C10.8946 2.41102 10.7864 2.3651 10.6549 2.3651H10.5506C10.4192 2.3651 10.3109 2.41102 10.2259 2.50287C10.1409 2.58706 10.0984 2.69039 10.0984 2.81286V7.18714C10.0984 7.31726 10.1409 7.42442 10.2259 7.50861C10.3109 7.5928 10.4192 7.6349 10.5506 7.6349H10.8753V8.50746H10.5506C10.3651 8.50746 10.1911 8.47302 10.0288 8.40413C9.86646 8.33525 9.72345 8.23957 9.59976 8.11711C9.48381 7.99464 9.39105 7.85687 9.32148 7.70379C9.2519 7.54305 9.21712 7.37084 9.21712 7.18714V2.81286C9.21712 2.62916 9.2519 2.46077 9.32148 2.30769C9.39105 2.14696 9.48381 2.00536 9.59976 1.88289C9.72345 1.76043 9.86646 1.66475 10.0288 1.59587C10.1911 1.52698 10.3651 1.49254 10.5506 1.49254H10.6549C10.8405 1.49254 11.0144 1.52698 11.1767 1.59587C11.3391 1.66475 11.4821 1.76043 11.6058 1.88289C11.7294 2.00536 11.8261 2.14696 11.8956 2.30769C11.9652 2.46077 12 2.62916 12 2.81286V8.69116C12 8.87486 11.9652 9.04325 11.8956 9.19633C11.8261 9.35706 11.7294 9.49483 11.6058 9.60964C11.4821 9.73211 11.3391 9.82778 11.1767 9.89667C11.0144 9.96556 10.8405 10 10.6549 10H10.11Z'
          fill='white'
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And in `Layout.tsx`

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ThemeProvider
          attribute='class'
          defaultTheme='system'
          enableSystem
          disableTransitionOnChange
        >
          <GlobalProviders>{children}</GlobalProviders>
        </ThemeProvider>
        <Toaster />
        <Loader />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

It work but it disappear rapidly without any animation. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

- For check that app is ready you can use [useTransition](https://react.dev/reference/react/useTransition) (react ^18)
- For out of the box animations, you can use [framer motion](https://www.framer.com/motion/)

Now. Your animation is in a component placed on root. When your app is ready, use `isPending`, when will be `false` (on initial will be `true`) fire your animation which will be on absolute display.

I don't wanna describe much, hope you will get it. It's not hard. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I really dont get how to do this :( Could you exaplain a little bit more?